# Getting an undefined 'map' reading when nesting .map functions

Tags: reactjs, methods, jsx, chakra-ui

I'm currently building a footer component for my website and I'm having trouble mapping through an inner array in my imported data object.

Here is **FooterData.js**. The arrays I'm mapping through.

```
// !! icons
import {
  RiDiscordLine as Discord,
  RiMailLine as Mail,
  RiPhoneLine as Phone
} from "react-icons/ri";

const FooterData = [
  {
    id: 2,
    category: "important",
    listItems: [
      {
        label: "Terms Of Service",
        link: "/Tos"
      },

      {
        label: "Privacy Policy",
        link: "/PrivacyPolicy"
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    id: 3,
    category: "links",
    listItems: [
      {
        label: "Home",
        link: "/"
      },
      {
        label: "About",
        link: "/about"
      },
      {
        label: "Contact",
        link: "/contact"
      },
      {
        label: "Gallery",
        link: "/gallery"
      },
      {
        label: "Get A Quote",
        link: "/quote"
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    id: 4,
    category: "Contact",
    listItems: [
      {
        label: "discord",
        icon: Discord,
        link: "/"
      },
      {
        label: "Email",
        icon: Mail,
        link: "/"
      }
    ]
  },


  {
    id: 1,
    category: 'main',
    img: '/Logo.png',
    text: 'Professional Web Design & Development Company Since 2023',
    listItems: [
        {
          label: "discord",
          icon: Discord,
          link: "/"
        },
        {
          label: "Email",
          icon: Mail,
          link: "/"
        }
      ]
  }
];

export default FooterData;
```

In the code below I can successfully map through and display all of the category labels.

but nested within that .map function I am trying to map through the listItem array.

It is returning this error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map'

```
import React from 'react';

import {Box,
Text,
Image,
SimpleGrid,
UnorderedList,
ListItem,
} from '@chakra-ui/react';

import Data from './Data';
import styles from './styles';

const Footer = () => {
// Index -1 to select that last item in the array
    const lastItem = Data.slice(-1)[0];

  return (
<Box sx={styles.container}>
  <SimpleGrid columns='4' spacing={5}>
    <Box>
      <Image src='/Logo.png'/>
      <Text as='p'>
        {lastItem.category === 'main' ? lastItem.text : null}
      </Text>
    </Box>
    {Data.map((item) => (
      <Box key={item.id}>
        <Text as='h4'>
          {item.category}
        </Text>
        <UnorderedList>
      {item.listItems.map((innerItem) => (
        <ListItem key={innerItem.link}>
            {innerItem.label}
        </ListItem>
      ))}
        </UnorderedList>
      </Box>
    ))}
  </SimpleGrid>
</Box>
  )
}

export default Footer
```

At first, I figured it might not be working since I had no listItems for one of the objects. After that turned out not to be the issue I was looking at examples online and running the code through an AI generator but could not figure out why I'm getting an undefined reading. Not sure what the problem might be.

Comment: Are you not supposed to import `FooterData` from `FooterData.js`? Also conventionally, components start with a capital letter and fields with a small letter. Go through the [Airbnb React guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react#basic-rules)

Comment: Does removing the inner map fix the issue?

Comment: @Konrad Yeah it does

Comment: Replace `listItems.map` with `listItems?.map`